# queryPurchases() returns an empty list

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have implemented the Billing library in order to have in-app products in my app. I can make a successful purchase and everything works fine. If I try to make a purchase again, I get the response "Product already owned" which shows that the purchase is fine. I am using as productID the test id: "android.test.purchased"

Moreover, in the Main's Activity onResume() method, I call the queryPurchases() method in order to restore the product in case the user deletes the app and re-installs it. However, this method returns an empty purchases list although the response code is OK.

This is the way I am using the method:

```
private fun startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(executeOnSuccess: Runnable?) {
    if (mBillingClient.isReady) {
        executeOnSuccess?.run()
    } else {
        mBillingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse billingResponse: Int) {
                if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: $billingResponse")
                    executeOnSuccess?.run()
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: $billingResponse")
                }
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()")
            }
        })
    }
}

// I call this method in Main's onResume()
fun updateBillingSharedPreferencesKey() {
    val executeOnConnectedService = Runnable {
        val purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        val purchasesList = purchasesResult?.purchasesList

        purchasesList?.let {
            // this list is always empty, although I have a valid product

            for (purchase in it) {
                // I never enter this loop to handle the product functionality
                Log.d(TAG, "purchase.sku = ${purchase?.sku}")
            }
        }
    }

    startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(executeOnConnectedService)
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The service connection and the response code is ok.
How should I call the queryPurchases() method to get my valid in-app product?

Comment: Do you have several google accounts on the test device ?

Comment: Were u able to resolve this issue?